# C#: looping over an xor key and bitshifting?

Tags: c#

I have a key stored as a 4-byte integer. Say

```
Int32 key = 12345678;
```

I have a byte array representing characters of an encrypted string

```
byte[] barray = ...
```

Now I want to loop over each byte and XOR with the corresponding byte in the key, looping the key when necessary.

```
1st byte ^= key & 0xFF
2nd byte ^= key & 0xFF 00
3rd byte ^= key & 0xFF 00 00
4th byte ^= key & 0xFF 00 00 00
5th byte ^= key & 0xFF
```

How do I write the loop? I started off with

```
for (int i = 0; i &lt; barray.length; i++)
{
   barray[i] ^= ???  
}
```

I'm not sure how to compute the correct byte to xor with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert the key into a byte array:

```
byte[] keyBytes;
unchecked
{
    keyBytes = new byte[]{(byte)(key >> 0),
                          (byte)(key >> 8),
                          (byte)(key >> 16),
                          (byte)(key >> 24);
}
```

I'm using this over `BitConverter` to achieve fixed endianness. Little endian in this example, but you can easily choose big endian, by listing the shiften bytes in reverse order.

And then you can use the remainder operator `%` to address the key bytes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < barray.length; i++)
{
    barray[i] ^= keyBytes[i%4];
}
```

What you're implementing is a [Vigenère cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) with a 4 byte keylength. So it's pretty easy to attack it. This is effectively only obfuscation, not real encryption.

Comment: Fixed endianness sounds like a good deal. Works perfectly for my needs.